# Html anchor height issue with unitless line heights

Tags: overflow, anchor, css

Trying to conform to [unitless line heights](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/) I have a problem with `overflow: auto` and anchor elements.
Consider the following simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="overflow: auto; background-color: #FFCCCC;">
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">Test</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The combination of `font-size: 12px` and `line-height: 1` should make the height of the paragraph and anchor (without padding, margin and border) 12 pixels.

The total height of the page should therefore be: 4 * 12 = 48 pixels (2 elements plus 2 * 12 pixels margin for the paragraph). However, almost every browser 'reserves' two or three extra pixels for underlining the anchor (even though I used `text-decoration: none`). Firefox 7, Chrome 14 and Opera 11.51 all show this behaviour, surprisingly IE9 works fine :).

With their respective developer toolbars, you can see that all browsers agree that the div element has a height of 48 pixels, but only IE thinks the anchors height is 12 pixels. Other browsers say 14 or 15 pixels, causing the scrollbar to appear.

When removing the `overflow: auto` is not an option (in my case the div is generated by a framework and sometimes just contains floating elements, so the overflow is used to extend the div to encapsulate its children), is there any proper solution to this? i.e. better than giving the anchor `font-size: 15px` or `line-height: 1.2` or something.

Cheers,
Moolie

Answer (score 3):

The issue only seems to happen if the `a` is touching the bottom of `#wrapper` directly. This means you can solve the problem in 3 ways:

1. put the link into a paragraph
2. set display block on the link and give it a margin
3. set a padding bottom on the wrapper

You'll have to decide if you find these more "clean".

Comment: Setting a padding bottom seems the cleanest solution to me.  But it makes you wonder why these browsers can't do math. Firebug for example is able to determine that the height of the link is 14px. Apparently the rendering engines don't always use the calculated height of children to determine the height of an element.  I guess the text-decoration option isn't the only one changing the dimensions of an element.

Comment: You might very well find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665443/text-decoration-being-cut-off-by-overflowhidden-in-certain-browsers/7665854 It was quite peculiar to have these 2 questions posted so fast one after the other, it highlights how difficult it must be for the guys working on browser engines.