# Text-decoration being cut off by overflow:hidden in certain browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, oocss

So I'm using the OOCSS media module and I'm putting a link inside of it and the last line of the link is being cut off.

To explain for anyone who doesn't know about the framework, it's simple to explain: imagine an element with overflow: hidden, and a link inside that element. That's ALL.

If I put a link inside of this element with overflow: hidden, the last text-decoration line of the link is cut off thanks to overflow: hidden. Without having to resort to padding &  margin (and hopefully floats) is there anyway to compensate for that last line being cut off? Chrome seems to get this right, not sure though.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you post a jsFiddle of the problem?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is .bd is a fixed size. It it were allowed to grow, then the overflow wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there was another question very similar to this recently, you can see my answer there: [Html anchor height issue with unitless line heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665258/html-anchor-height-issue-with-unitless-line-heights/7665546#7665546)

So I don't think there's a solution to your question, but I wanted to note that while Chrome gets it right for overflow hidden, when you use overflow auto it's actually a problem as you'll see in that post.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the line height on the text

```
line-height:1.5;
```

Comment: Doesn't help me: if the font-size is 12px, and I add that declaration, yeah it will work, but I don't want the line-height to be that big. I want to declare a line-height close to the size I gave for the font.

Comment: if it is a browser bug this will be the only fix. the underline is placed outside the line-height, so line-height:1.1 or lesser values will work good

Comment: That's the thing: I'm not sure if it's a Browser bug, or if my code makes that work specifically in one browser, and I think other browsers get it wrong / right so it can't be chalked up as just that. The less the line-height, the more the issue also.